# get days starting from epoch

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I want count of days starting from epoch(1970-01-01). I tried with joda-time

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2013-05-03 07:00:00");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("2013-05-03 23:30:00");


    MutableDateTime epoch = new MutableDateTime();
    epoch.setDate(0); //Set to Epoch time
    System.out.println("Epoch: " + epoch);
    Days days1 = Days.daysBetween(epoch, new MutableDateTime(date1.getTime()));
    Days days2 = Days.daysBetween(epoch, new MutableDateTime(date2.getTime()));
    System.out.println("1) Days Since Epoch: " + days1.getDays());
    System.out.println("2) Days Since Epoch: " + days2.getDays());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

and using logic:

```
// Create Calendar instance
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(date);
    // Set the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH.
```

//      calendar1.set(calendar1.YEAR, calendar1.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        calendar1.set(1970, 1, 1);

```
    /*
     * Use getTimeInMillis() method to get the Calendar's time value in
     * milliseconds. This method returns the current time as UTC
     * milliseconds from the epoch
     */
    long miliSecondForDate1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long miliSecondForDate2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

    // Calculate the difference in millisecond between two dates
    long diffInMilis = miliSecondForDate2 - miliSecondForDate1;

    /*
     * Now we have difference between two date in form of millsecond we can
     * easily convert it Minute / Hour / Days by dividing the difference
     * with appropriate value. 1 Second : 1000 milisecond 1 Hour : 60 * 1000
     * millisecond 1 Day : 24 * 60 * 1000 milisecond
     */

    long diffInSecond = diffInMilis / 1000;
    long diffInMinute = diffInMilis / (60 * 1000);
    long diffInHour = diffInMilis / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    long diffInDays = diffInMilis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    if(logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("Difference in Seconds : " + diffInSecond);
        logger.info("Difference in Minute : " + diffInMinute);
        logger.info("Difference in Hours : " + diffInHour);
        logger.info("Difference in Days : " + diffInDays);
    }
```

I am getting diff result for both of this. can somebody help where i am wrong.

thanks.

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: For same date i am getting: `1) Days Since Epoch: 17007
2) Days Since Epoch: 17006
17/03/28 14:35:40 INFO query.DateUtil: Difference in Seconds : 1466708059
17/03/28 14:35:40 INFO query.DateUtil: Difference in Minute : 24445134
17/03/28 14:35:40 INFO query.DateUtil: Difference in Hours : 407418
17/03/28 14:35:40 INFO query.DateUtil: Difference in Days : 16975
`

Comment: It could be a time zone issue. Do you want to count days in your time zone, in UTC, or…?

Comment: How timezone effect here both run on my machine

Comment: For `2013-05-03` (May 3rd, 2013), I believe the correct answer is 15828. I am not finished wondering how you got 16975, 17006 and 17007.

Comment: i checked for `2016-07-25 and 2016-07-26` and i got this result. Can you help me analyse why it is giving 25 days difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between 17006 and 17007 is one day. This difference very likely comes from 7:00 and 23:30 in your time zone are on different days in some other time zone, say, UTC. Or the other way around, those times in UTC happen to be on different days in your time zone. Therefore the count is off by one. I don’t know JodaTime, so I cannot give you the precise details.

The difference between 16975 and 17006 is 31 days or a full month. I *can* tell you exactly where this comes from. `Calendar` months are 0-based: January is month 0, February is 1, etc. So `calendar1.set(1970, 1, 1)` sets your Calendar to *February* 1, 1970, 31 days after the epoch. Use `calendar1.set(1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1)` instead. You will also want to control the hours, minutes and seconds of the `Calendar`. You may call `clear()` before `set()` to make sure the time is at midnight.

If you can use Java 8, you may do:

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    OffsetDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-05-03 07:00:00", format)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    OffsetDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-05-03 23:30:00", format)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    System.out.println("1) Days Since Epoch: " + ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.EPOCH, t1));
    System.out.println("2) Days Since Epoch: " + ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.EPOCH, t2));
```

This prints:

```
1) Days Since Epoch: 15828
2) Days Since Epoch: 15828
```

If you want to use a different time zone:

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    ZonedDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-05-03 07:00:00", format)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-05-03 23:30:00", format)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    System.out.println("1) Days Since Epoch: " + ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.EPOCH, t1));
    System.out.println("2) Days Since Epoch: " + ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.EPOCH, t2));
```

You can fill in the desired time zone instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Comment: Just to inform you Ole. Jodatime is included as java.time from java 8 version.

Comment: Ah, from what I’ve been told elsewhere, you are oversimplifying a little bit there, @PPunam. I heard that `java.time` is largely built on the best parts of JodaTime, it’s not an exact copy. But thanks for mentioning.

Comment: While exploring jodatime, i read it on its site "Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project"

Comment: @PPunam True, but you suggest java.time is excerpted from Joda-Time. Not true at all. While Joda-Time inspired java.time, and both projects are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne, java.time is a completely new re-write, re-engineered from scratch, with a new design benefitting from what was learned on Joda-Time. But java.time is *not* a drop-in replacement for Joda-Time. Fortunately, a programmer using Joda-Time can leave her existing code in place as she learns to write new code using java.time. Just be careful with `import` statements as a few of the classes share the same name.